# Can't understand perl regex to unquote meta

Tags: regex, perl

I came across this awesome regex:

`s/((?:\\[a-zA-Z\\])+)/qq[qq[$1]]/eeg`

It does magic, but is so obscure I can't understand it. It works very well:

```
echo 'a\tb\nc\r\n' | perl -lpe 's/((?:\\[a-zA-Z\\])+)/qq[qq[$1]]/eeg'
a   b
c
```

Let us watch it with `cat -A` :

```
echo 'a\tb\nc\r\n' | perl -lpe 's/((?:\\[a-zA-Z\\])+)/qq[qq[$1]]/eeg' | cat -A
a^Ib$
c^M$
$
```

I will keep it for future reference, but it would be really cool to understand it. I know `/ee` modifier evaluates `RHS`,  but what are those `qq`s?  Is the function `qq` for double quotes ? I would appreciate if someone could explain.

PS. I found this regex [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.perl.misc/LSdUAeBUkx0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In perl re's you have single and double quotes, where "$foo" is expanded and '$foo' is literal.

The `q` operator lets you set which character does `'`
The `qq`operator sets the character for `"`.

So in the awesome example, `[` is getting set to expand variables, and perl magic is making it more readable by pairing `]` with `[`.  So it's expanding the variable twice, which without that highlighting would be deeply mysterious, and the `"` quotes get very confusing when mixed in with shell quoting.

A simple example to try out :

```
% perl -E '$foo=bar; say qq[$foo];'
bar
%
```

Comment: I suspected that was the qq function, had just edited my question when you answered :) +1 thanks

Answer (score 1):

`qq` is the interpolating quote operator. It's the same thing as putting a string between double quotes, but can use open-close character pairs like `[]` here. This has the advantage that you can nest it, which you couldn't do with double quotes.

Comment: I suspected that was the `qq` function, had just edited my question when you answered :) +1 thanks